# What is the best way to run npm packages on demand as mircoservices without installing it locally?

Tags: node.js, npm, microservices

Let's say I have these npm packages published to npm:
`service1@v1.0`
`service1@v2.0`
`service2@v1.0`
each package has a single function:

```
function run(extraStr) {
  return 'package_name_and_version' + extraStr; // i.e. service1 v1.0 extraStr
}
```

And I want to write nodejs code that use the packages without installing it locally

```
var server = require("my-server-sdk");
  // get(package_name, version, function_in_package, arguments, callback)
  server.get('service1', '2.0', 'run', ['app1'], (err, result) => {
  console.log(result); // this should print service1 v2.0 app1
});
```

where `my-server-sdk` is an sdk that interface with my server's api where it **install the required packages and cache it for later use**.
What is the best way to do that? what the security concerns and how to prevent any?

this is a simple diagram for what I want
[image]

NOTE: `service1@v1.0`
`service1@v2.0`
`service2@v1.0`
are just examples to any packages in npm i.e. `lodash`

---

**Caching example:**

Let's say we have TTL equal **60 minutes**.

**client1** requested a function from `lodash` and another function from `underscore` at 01:00.
Now in the server `lodash` and `underscore` are installed with timestamp **01:00**.

**client2** requested a function from `underscore` at **01:30** which get used instantly because `underscore` is installed before but it timestamp got updated to **1:30**.

At **02:01** `lodash` get deleted because it didn't get used on the past TTL `currenttime - lodash_timestamp > TTL` but `underscore` stays because `currenttime - underscore_timestamp < TTL`

So when **client3** request `lodash` at **02:30** it get `intsalled` again with **02:30** as a `timestamp`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem you're trying to solve.  NPM already handles the versioning for you.  `require()` caches.  Why wouldn't you want to install your SDK locally?  What sort of security concerns are you asking about?

Comment: @Brad I want to use npm packages as microservices without installing it locally, the only think I want to install is the SDK which interfaces with my server to run the microservices.
Security concerns like calling a function that deletes files from the server (I want each package to run in a sandbox)

Comment: I still don't understand what it is exactly you're trying to do.  Your SDK can just be a client to your services.  SDK or no, if you're not preventing people from deleting stuff on your servers anyway, it can be done by hitting your services directly.  If you want to run code locally, you must have that code.  While you could fetch and evaluate that JavaScript, you're creating unnecessary complexity for zero gain.  Why does it matter if it's on-disk or not?  Someone could just dump your code to disk anyway.  And, it's not as if a microservice client is hiding anything...

Comment: If i understand the question you want to tell your server to "npm install MODULE", import it, run a specific method from this module and return the results. Please give some feedback on this so I can post some code I have in mind.

Comment: @alex-rokabilis exactly and note that I can call functions from the same package but with different version

Comment: I have added simple diagram demonstrating what I want to do, thanks :)

Comment: For me it's also not really clear. Do you mean that app1 and app2 are clients, which access the server (your last snippet, is that executed inside of app1 or app2?). You agreed with @alex-rokabilis but you also said `without installing it locally` that is confusing.

Comment: @timaschew app1 and app2 are clients which access the server and request a result from a function in npm package (the server install the packages and process everything, the clients just retrieve the results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [npmi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npmi) package which gives an API to npm install.

The logic I would use is:

1. Get the specific package and version from npm (install if is not already installed)
2. Require the package inside nodejs
3. Run the specified method with the specified parameters
4. Return the results to the client

```js
var npmi = require('npmi');
var path = require('path');

function runModule(moduleName, moduleVersion, moduleMethod, moduleMethodParams) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var options = {
      name: moduleName, // your module name 
      version: moduleVersion, // expected version [default: 'latest'] 
      forceInstall: false, // force install if set to true (even if already installed, it will do a reinstall) [default: false] 
      npmLoad: { // npm.load(options, callback): this is the "options" given to npm.load() 
        loglevel: 'silent' // [default: {loglevel: 'silent'}] 
      }
    };
    options.path = './' + options.name + "@" + options.version,
      npmi(options, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          if (err.code === npmi.LOAD_ERR) console.log('npm load error');
          else if (err.code === npmi.INSTALL_ERR) console.log('npm install error');
          console.log(err.message);
          return reject(err)
        }

        // installed 
        console.log(options.name + '@' + options.version + ' installed successfully in ' + path.resolve(options.path));

        var my_module = require(path.resolve(options.path, "node_modules", options.name))

        console.log("Running :", options.name + '@' + options.version)
        console.log("Method :", moduleMethod);
        console.log("With params :", ...moduleMethodParams)
        resolve(my_module[moduleMethod](...moduleMethodParams))
      });

  })

}

runModule('lodash', '4.10.0', 'fill', [Array(3), 2])
  .then(result => console.log("Result :", result))

runModule('lodash', '3.10.0', 'fill', [Array(3), 2])
  .then(result => console.log("Result :", result))
```

You could see now that there are 2 created folders **(lodash@3.10.0 , lodash@4.10.0)** indicating the package name and version.

I have made the assumptions that npm is in path and the server has the permissions to install packages in current directory, also that the **"MODULE_NAME@MODULE_VERSION"** is a valid folder name under the current OS.

Comment: I liked that, thanks alex. What do you think the best way to implement cache system where packages that didn't get used before TTL, got deleted?

Comment: I didn't understand that. Can you provide more information? Or an example would be better.

Comment: what is the benefit of pulling this kind of buildtime logic into runtime?

Comment: @timaschew It has a lof of benefits actually some of it: 
1- you can use packages across different programming languages i.e. python, java.
2- If you have a bug in a package you can update it individually without worrying about updating each client every time you update a package
3- Splitting code into self-contained microservices make it easy to test each part individually and develop real-time apps

Comment: @alex-rokabilis I have added caching example to the question. I think caching is important in this type of systems to save space from least used packages, what do you think?

Comment: @timaschew after listing some the benefits to such system, what do you think? I really want opinions on this. thanks

Comment: @Divoo I understand now what you are saying. I dont think it's so important to create this kind of cache unless you are really limited on space. Anyway as in your example, you can constantly create timeouts on installation to delete a module after a fixed TTL and clear this timeout when the module runs again.

Comment: @Divoo You should be very carefull on permissions with this approach, someone could easily run any code on your system right now, you really need to limit with OS this process to do only a specific set of operations. Although if someone knows what he is doing, things could be really bad, he could run cpu bound operation that never let nodejs go to the next cycle and stall your server or even worse...

Comment: @alex-rokabilis could you give me any suggestions on how to protect my system from such operations?

Comment: @Divoo What you've explained is related to "hiding" all the services behind the "server". Instead of letting the apps directly use the services. I agree on that. But if we just speak in the context of the server, I don't see a benefit of installing the modules via API at runtime. Handling dependencies is not really trivial and I don't think you are able to handle all the edge cases via the API (`npmi`) which are done via npm CLI or yarn. Also `npmi` looks a bit outdated.

Comment: @timachew what do think is the best solution? how to get the same benefits using other techniques?